# How to get around SSL cert warning HttpWebRequest .NET

Tags: .net, ssl, https, httpwebrequest, warnings

I am using .NET WebRequest to browse to my web server as local host. This is to run some timed services.
My problem is for PCI compliance I now have to turn off HTTP
Changing this webrequest to use HTTPS instead of HTTP gives a security cert warning since the cert is connected to my domain name not my internal ip address this webrequest is using.

There are various workarounds which are not ideal like setting up an internal web site on http just to run these services.

I just hought of something.
Maybe I can manually browse using IE and then tell IE to permanently accept this security warning?

What I would really like to have is a way to programmatically answer the security warning and get by it like you can if you were manually using a web browser to browse to local host.

```
    protected static string GetPage(string url, int timeout)
    {
        WebResponse response = null;
        Stream stream = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            // Try to upen the url
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            if (timeout > 0)
                request.Timeout = timeout * 1000;   // convert to seconds
            response = request.GetResponse();

            // We're expecting html text -- not a pdf, xls, etc. file
            if (!response.ContentType.ToLower().StartsWith("text/"))
                return null;

            stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Web Exception");
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("IO Exception");
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();

            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();

            if (response != null)
                response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

Comment: Just add the target hosts name as an alternative name to localhost by editing the local hosts file. No changes are needed on the program then for testing.

Comment: 1) ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
It looks like this opens up what looks like a significant security hole globally on the server.

2) I can't add the domain name to the hosts file pointing to the internal IP. I already thought of that.
The problem is there is code on the the server that uses the domain name and this domain name has to resolve to the outside IP address.

Thanks for the answers anyways.